# Is pythonanywhere capable to respond with a HTTP 200 status?

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I plan to host my flask-sqlalchemy-python3.6 app on pythonanywhere but need to work with Paddle too.
Will my app be able to feed Paddle's webhook needs as on: https://developer.paddle.com/webhook-reference/intro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. That's the HTTP success code.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Worked even on free account, very important while testing